# Automatically deploy Node.js + React monorepo to Raspberry Pi devices

Tags: node.js, server, raspberry-pi, architecture

I'm currently developing an Node.js + React monorepo application which needs to run locally inside several Raspberries.

It would be impossible to manually connect to every and each Raspberry to update the build files when there're updates to the source code.

Which alternatives are available so when we push to the monorepo main branch, the build files are automatically update inside every Raspberry?

Comment: You can build a docker image of your application, and run on each raspberry alongside with https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower

Comment: Then add some github action that will do docker build and push on every git push